# Why visual studio is linking MSVCR90.dll (x86) on 64 Bit platform?

Tags: c++, matlab, 32bit-64bit, mex, msvcr90.dll

I'm writing a library for MATLAB (mex-file). While developing I used the debug profile in Visual Studio 2008. Everything is fine in debug mode. MATLAB executes my library correctly.

When I switch to relase mode in visual studio, MATLAB is unable to load my library (dll named as .mexw64). Using Dependency Walker I saw that the debug version is linking the MSVCR90D.dll (x64) but the release version is linking the MSVCR90.dll (x86).

Debug Configuration: /MDd
Release Configuration: /MD

Any ideas?

Comment: Use Build + Configuration Manager.

Comment: How have you tested it is actually 32-bit version of DLL? The name is same for 32-bit and 64-bit, but they are different files.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah. You did not turn your project to 64 bit in the release configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Using dependency walker I've found that it wasn't my program, it was Oracle's oraocci11d.dll that was compiled using visual studio 9, so it needed msvcr90d.dll. I just downloaded the library compiled in VS 2010

Answer (score 0):

You may have a manifest file somewhere that is wrongfully specifying the architecture (as x86) of libmsvcrt.